# Create new object by sorting array of objects key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of objects consisting of items:

```
[
  {
    CATEGORY:"Fruits"
    ITEM_AVAIL:true
    ITEM_NAME:"Apple"
    ITEM_PRICE:100
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg"
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object
    ORDER_COUNT:0

  },
  {
    CATEGORY:"Vegetables"
    ITEM_AVAIL:true
    ITEM_NAME:"Aloo"
    ITEM_PRICE:1000
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg"
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object
    ORDER_COUNT:0

  }
]
```

I want create a new object such that each key of the object is a category and holds the array of objects of items, for example:

```
{
  Fruits: [
    {
    CATEGORY:"Fruits"
    ITEM_AVAIL:true
    ITEM_NAME:"Apple"
    ITEM_PRICE:100
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg"
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object
    ORDER_COUNT:0
    },
    //more fruits
    ]
  Vegetables: [
    {
    CATEGORY:"Vegetables"
    ITEM_AVAIL:true
    ITEM_NAME:"Aloo"
    ITEM_PRICE:1000
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg"
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object
    ORDER_COUNT:0
    },
    //more vegetables
    ]
}
```

the new object will be created based on category of item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map to group elements by category as the key, and the list of items as the value:

```js
let items = [
  {
    CATEGORY:"Fruits",
    ITEM_AVAIL:true,
    ITEM_NAME:"Apple",
    ITEM_PRICE:100,
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
    ORDER_COUNT:0
  },
  {
    CATEGORY:"Vegetables",
    ITEM_AVAIL:true,
    ITEM_NAME:"Aloo",
    ITEM_PRICE:1000,
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
    ORDER_COUNT:0
  },
  {
    CATEGORY:"Fruits",
    ITEM_AVAIL:true,
    ITEM_NAME:"Apple1",
    ITEM_PRICE:200,
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
    ORDER_COUNT:0
  },
  {
    CATEGORY:"Vegetables",
    ITEM_AVAIL:true,
    ITEM_NAME:"Aloo1",
    ITEM_PRICE:2000,
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
    ORDER_COUNT:0
  },
]
let obj = {};
items.forEach((item) => {
     if(!obj[item.CATEGORY])
          obj[item.CATEGORY] = [ item ];
     else
          obj[item.CATEGORY].push(item);
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create new object like this

```js
var data = [
      {
        CATEGORY:"Fruits",
        ITEM_AVAIL:true,
        ITEM_NAME:"Apple",
        ITEM_PRICE:100,
        ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
        ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
        ORDER_COUNT:0,

      },
      {
        CATEGORY:"Vegetables",
        ITEM_AVAIL:true,
        ITEM_NAME:"Aloo",
        ITEM_PRICE:1000,
        ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
        ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
        ORDER_COUNT:0,

      }
    ];
var newobj = [];
for (i in data){        
    newobj[i] = [];
    newobj[i][data[i].CATEGORY] = data[i];
}       
console.log(newobj);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work properly. Result: `[ [], [] ]`.

Comment: @Sascha yeah you are right but why my browser is giving correct output. can you tell me the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Look if for the actual object there exists a property with this category as name. If not so create it with an empty array as value. In both cases ass to this array the object.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    CATEGORY:"Fruits",
    ITEM_AVAIL:true,
    ITEM_NAME:"Apple",
    ITEM_PRICE:100,
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
    ORDER_COUNT:0,
  },
  {
    CATEGORY:"Vegetables",
    ITEM_AVAIL:true,
    ITEM_NAME:"Aloo",
    ITEM_PRICE:1000,
    ITEM_UNIT:"per_kg",
    ITEM_UPDATED:Object,
    ORDER_COUNT:0,
  }
];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc[cur.CATEGORY]) {
        acc[cur.CATEGORY] = [];
    }
    acc[cur.CATEGORY].push(cur);
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(res);
```